# Why does query execution continue after RETURN?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider following script:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#INTERMED', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #INTERMED; 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#INTERMED1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #INTERMED1; 

PRINT 'Inserting INTO #INTERMED'
GO

SELECT 11 AS Col1
INTO #INTERMED

RETURN -- Why does execution continue below this line?

PRINT 'Inserting INTO #INTERMED1' -- This doesn't print anything
GO
SELECT 'Testing testing 123' AS Col2 
INTO #INTERMED1

SELECT * FROM #INTERMED1 i
```

When you run it in SSMS you will notice that RETURN is ignored, PRINT statement after RETURN doesn't do anything and then execution continues.

Can someone explain why? I would expect it to exit immediately after RETURN.

I did find that it is somehow related to GO statements because if I commented out all GO statements it behaves as expected (exits after RETURN) but I still don't have an explanation.

Comment: Because you have a GO. A GO in MS T-Sql acts as a completely new script batch. What are you using go for anyway?

Comment: GO defines the batch statement -- when you run this you are running 3 separate statements -- return exists from the current one and runs the next.

Comment: Charleh: this is a simplified version of original script. Original script has multiple parts that take a while to execute. The reason I had GO in it is to actually have PRINT statements output something while script is still executing.

Comment: See the bottom my answer for a better way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GO` is *not part of the SQL Language*. It's a batch separator used by *Management Studio*, and adopted as a convention by some other tools as well, but it has no special meaning in the language itself. Try to use it in a stored procedure and see what I mean.

Therefore, what happens is you have one batch the looks like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#INTERMED', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #INTERMED; 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#INTERMED1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #INTERMED1; 

PRINT 'Inserting INTO #INTERMED'
```

It does it's thing, and then you have a new batch that looks like this:

```
SELECT 11 AS Col1
INTO #INTERMED

RETURN -- Why does execution continue below this line?

PRINT 'Inserting INTO #INTERMED1' -- This doesn't print anything
```

It runs to the `RETURN` statement, at which point the *batch*, and only that batch, returns/finishes. However, there is still one more batch to run:

```
SELECT 'Testing testing 123' AS Col2 
INTO #INTERMED1

SELECT * FROM #INTERMED1 i
```

Again, this is a whole new batch. The previous `RETURN` statement means nothing. It's like you called three methods in sequence.

---

I also saw this in the comments:

> The reason I had GO in it is to actually have PRINT statements output something while script is still executing.

There's a better way. Look into the `RAISERROR` statement:

```
RAISERROR('My Progress Message',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
```

Comment: Good tip about using RAISERROR instead of PRINT. I commented out GO and replaced PRINT with RAISERROR. It works but is it guaranteed it will not interrupt execution if I use 0 for severity?

Comment: I looked more into using RAISERROR and your example needs to have WITH NOWAIT added at the end

Comment: 0 for severity is safe, and thanks for reminding me about nowait. I'll edit when I'm at a normal keyboard instead of my phone.